# $scope.$watch function does not reflect changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

$scope.$watch function does not reflect changes made to $scope.Fruits.
$scope.Fruits gets updated in HTML when respected filter is applied.
I think it is because of the 'return' in $scope.colorFilter Function. I am not able to find any way around it.

Javascript is as follows:

```
 angular.module('fruit', []);

function FruitCtrl($scope) {
$scope.fruit = [
    {'name': 'Apple', 'colour': 'Red'},
    {'name': 'Orange', 'colour': 'Orange'},
    {'name': 'Banana', 'colour': 'Yellow'}
];

$scope.colourIncludes = [];

$scope.includeColour = function(colour) {
    var i = $.inArray(colour, $scope.colourIncludes);
    if (i > -1) {
        $scope.colourIncludes.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.colourIncludes.push(colour);
    }
}

$scope.colourFilter = function(fruit) {

    if ($scope.colourIncludes.length > 0) {
        if ($.inArray(fruit.colour, $scope.colourIncludes) < 0){
          alert('hi');
            return;
        }

    }

    return fruit;
}

$scope.$watch('Fruits', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log($scope.Fruits);
                    console.log(newValue);
                    console.log(oldValue);
    }, true)

 }
```

HTML File:

```
 <div ng-app="fruit">
<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Red')"/> Red</br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Orange')"/> Orange</br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Yellow')"/> Yellow</br/>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="f in fruit | filter:colourFilter">
            {{f.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    Filter dump: {{colourIncludes}}
</div>
```

Comment: watch should be on `fruit` not `Fruit` like `$scope.$watch('fruits'`

Comment: I have replaced 'Fruits' with 'fruit'...but still I am not getting newValue or oldValue.

Answer (score 0):

The `$watch` method accepts two parameters for what you are trying to do:

- the name of the variable you want to watch for (`fruits`, in this instance)
- the closure you want to call when there is a change on that variable in the scope

In your case you need to change `Fruits` to `fruit` since that is your variable name, if you'd rather use `Fruits` to refer to these fruits, you can always adjust the scope and view as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a change is detected, the listener callback is fired.

Comment: I tried using $watchCollection but still...no result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `$watch` function refers to the wrong variable. The first parameter should be the name of the variable inside the scope that you want to watch for changes. In this case, it is called `fruit`, not `Fruits`. From what I can tell, there is no scope variable named `Fruits` and so that watch function will never fire.

Take a look at the [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for more information.

Also, since you brought up your `colorFilter` function, I thought I'd give a comment in regards to that.

In my experience, a filter function used in the way you have done (a scope function that is referenced by in the HTML via a `filter:` attribute) should return either `true` or `false` based on your logic.

So basically, something like this:

```
$scope.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
    if ($scope.colourIncludes.length > 0) {
        if ($.inArray(fruit.colour, $scope.colourIncludes) < 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Lets say I want to re-assign $scope.fruit with filterd result, how should that be done????

Comment: You would have to redefine `$scope.fruit`. The only point of a filter is to modify the view based on criteria. The items that don't fit your `colorFilter` algorithm aren't removed from `$scope.fruit`, they simply aren't shown in the view. If you redefine your filter mid-runtime, those items will reappear if they fit the filter now, because they were never removed from the array.